# Laravel Filament big file upload error in cPanel

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

I'm using Laravel Filament admin panel for my project. The issue is that I can't upload a 50MB PDF file in the live project.

I updated `max_file_size` and `max_file_upload` in my cPanel & checked everything, but I still can't upload the large file. The code is working fine on my local computer, but not in cPanel.

I checked the PHP version & other things.

I tried to update the composer, checked the php.ini files, updated some PHP global variables in php.ini also.

Answer (score 1):

Sample PHP script to check

```php
$maxFileUploadSize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
$maxPostSize = ini_get('post_max_size');
```

if ok as per your settings and not working then

check memory_limit,max_execution_time apart from this you can look into php_value and web servers as it has its  own configuration settings

in your case of Laravel check the File Upload Configuration where you are not overriding any PHP settings

**Recommendation**: Do file upload chunking in your file upload process, especially if you are using shared hosting as they have restrictions